# Groups.Add does not immediately add the caller into the group

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following code:

```
public void JoinGroup(string groupName, string userFullName)
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    // Send data back to everyone including the caller   
    Clients.Group(groupName).dataChanged(...);
}
```

I would expect `Clients.Group(groupName)` to call back to the client who just joined the group but it does not. `Clients.Caller...` however does correctly call the client who just joined the group.

**QUESTION**

Why isn't `Clients.Group(groupName)` including the caller who just joined the group?

Comment: Did you test to make sure the caller successfully joined the group?

Comment: Hmm I would expect `Add` to throw in case the operation fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Groups.Add` is async, so you need to await it if you want to use the group in the same method ([as stated in the documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/working-with-groups#add)):

```
public async Task JoinGroup(string groupName, string userFullName)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    // Send data back to everyone including the caller   
    Clients.Group(groupName).dataChanged(...);
}
```